# What is the point of self.x = x?

Tags: python, class

```
class Car:

def __init__(self,make,model,year):
    self.make=make
    self.model=model
    self.year=year
#---snipped code
```

- Why can it not be *make = self.make* i.e. the reverse?
- What is exactly the point of
  *self.make = make* assignment?

Comment: *make* is a parameter of  `__init__`, `self.make` is an attribute of the class, these two *make* do not refer to the same element

Comment: All of your questions are answered in almost any tutorial on classes.  We expect you to consult available documentation and examples before posting here.

Comment: because self, make, model and year are arguments of the functions but they're also the names of the atributes for that object. That way you can differenciate an attribute with self from the argument

Comment: @Prune: I only came here as a last resort since I couldn't understand from books. Please don't assume I didn't consult.

Comment: Its a question of namespaces. The variable `make` is local to one instance of the `__init__` function and is deleted when `__init__` returns. `self` is a reference to the object's namespace. Nothing says that `__init__` parameters should be saved on an instance of the class, you have to make that decision yourself. `self.make = make` is the simplest option. But you could do more complicated things like `self.make_model = make, model` if you had a reason to hold data that way.

Comment: Your original question was markedly better than after your edits. I would suggest that you roll back to the first revision.

Comment: Thanks, its done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `self` refers to the current object and `self.make` is an attribute of this object. The variable `make` is just a local variable whose scope ends at the end of the `__init__` method. The assignment thus serves to save this variable into the object so that its other methods can refer to it, vaguely like a global variable except it's local to this class, and each instance of the class (each object) has its own private copy.